# "No C# project is currently loaded" in Visual Studio Code when debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I only get such an error when I press F5(run) in C#, all libraries are installed, .Net is installed. I deleted the app and reinstalled it but it didn't work.

Can you help me?(

[image]

> No C# project is currently loaded. Please create a C# project in order to debug.
>
> Source: C# Dev Kit (Extension)

When I press F5, the code does not work and I get an error as in the picture

Comment: Could you please share your solution explorer, it will help use to understand the problem easily. Do you have .csproj file in your folder?

Comment: What do you have selected in the solution explorer when you type F5? Do you have a .vscode/launch.json file in the solution folder?

Comment: Are you targeting .net8-macos?

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was following a couple different (older) walk throughs that used a mix of Command Pallet commands to create the C# project and solution.

```
dotnet new console
dotnet new sln
```

In the terminal I could run the project.

```
dotnet run
```

But I could not debug. Then I figured out that the "project" was not associated with the "solution". At the bottom of the Explorer pane open the Solution Explorer. If necessary, create a folder and then right click and **Add Existing Project...** Choose the `csproj` file in your directory and save everything.

[image: VSCode Solution Explorer | Add Existing Project]

Return to the Run and Debug tab and  hit [F5].

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a simple change of directories. My folder has a root directory with frontend and backend respectively. I've opened up the backend solution in the VS code file manager, instead of the root directory where the `.sln` was. Upon changing to root director, the debug started working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but this solution worked for me.

.NET won't let simply create the files and run; you have to create a new .NET project of your choosing and go from there.

If you type "> .NET: New Project" into the search bar at the top and center of the screen, you'll get a drop-down menu to select the type of project you wish to create.  If you don't know, you can just select "Console App". From there, name your project and select where you would like to save it.  If you're not starting from scratch, you'll have to port over any code you wish to use into the project.

The ">" symbol in the search bar brings forward the run commands.  You can just select it from the drop-down after clicking the search bar if you prefer, or press "control + shift + p". This will show you some of your other options outside of creating a new project.

I hope this was helpful; good luck!

Comment: I tried this, but nothing happened. Where are the files created? I expected the working directory, but apparently not...